# How to read the exported keywords from a Lightroom image file

Tags: lightroom

I have this JPEG file in Lightroom. This file has a set of a set of keywords. Lightroom will show you the "Will Export" keywords. Now I would like to extract those "Will Export" keywords and place these keywords in another file. How to do this ? I am not a programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with a 'Lightroom Image file jpeg' - jpeg is not a Lightroom format, but a standard picture format, that LightRoom is able to read.

Any meta data in a jpeg is stored within the EXIF area (for EXtended INformation) of the file, and you need a tool to read it out.

1. There are many free tools that read various parts of the EXIF data and display it or do other things. You can google for EXIF to find some (there are a lot of bad ones too, so be careful). Some may allow extracting data like the keywords to an extra file, via command line interface.
2. In LightRoom, there is a setting that allows to write meta data into a separate file (*.xmp); you can change that in the options. That file will be in an XML format, and will contain the keywords (plus other stuff). You can see the keywords with an XML editor (again,many free ones exist), and maybe some have command line interfaces too.

There is no direct way to just extract those keywords; they are a part of hundreds of EXIF data elements, buried in the middle of them.

Comment: EXIF is an acronym for "EXchangeable Image Format," not "EXtended INformation."

Comment: sorry, I had formulate my question more precise. I will edit the question